# How to avoid relayout of content in a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is what I read in the cells and table view performance guide :

> Avoid relayout of content. When reusing cells with custom subviews,
>   refrain from laying out those subviews each time the table view
>   requests a cell. Lay out the subviews once, when the cell is created.

What does it mean ?

Am I applying this :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.customCellDescription.text = data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is fine. You are putting data in the label (or whatever it is), not moving it around. That is exactly what `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is for — to apply to the cell the data that corresponds to this index path.

Answer (score 1):

It mean that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` you just set data to present for each cell and avoid change frame or add something in here. Now generally we use prototype cell and set frame on storyboard. So it is don't matter.